# Loader image not working on the safari device

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, settimeout, loader

Loader image not working on the safari device
On clicking the search button, I am trying show a loader on my page before redirecting to the result page.
The loader image is populated only on the chrome browser and not on the safari browser. The loader is visible on safari browser only when I try to debug this code or try to add an alert.
I have also tried to fix this code by adding setTimeOut but it did not work.

The code changes are below:

```
function showMainLoader() {
    // **** alert("test");  // Uncommenting this line will show me the loader image
    $('#content').hide();   
    $('#loadingTLoader').show();
    interstitialLoader("#interstitialLoaderStandalone", "Looking for results...", "medium", false); 
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    function validateStandAloneForm() {
        $('#findStandAlone').validate({
            onfocusout: function (element) {
                $(element).valid();
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                $('#loaderT').css("margin-top", "4em");
                $('#loaderT').css("margin-left", "20em");
                showMainLoader();
                return true;
            },
            rules: {
                firstName: {
                    required: true,                 
                },
                lastName: {
                    required: true,
                },
                .
                .
                .
                ......// so on
            }
        });
    }
    $('#findFButtonStandAlone').click(function () {
            validateStandAloneForm();
            var standAloneBRef = $("#findStandAlone").find('#mbsBookingRef').val();
            var standAloneBRefVal = standAloneBRef.replace(/\s+/g, '');

            var standAloneFirstName = $("#findStandAlone").find("#mbsFirstname").val();

            var standAloneFirstNameVal = standAloneFirstName.replace(/[^A-Za-z\x2D\xC0-\xFF\s]+/g,'');

            var standAloneLastName = $("#findStandAlone").find("#mbsLastname").val();

            var standAloneLastNameVal = standAloneLastName.replace(/[^A-Za-z\x2D\xC0-\xFF\s]+/g,'');
            .
            .
            .....// so on
    });
});

function interstitialLoader(a, b, c, d) {
    var e = "<div class='loadingContainer'><span class='aria-hidden' aria-live='assertive' id='LoadingId1' aria-atomic='true'></span>"+
    "   <img src='" + imgPath + "/content/images/sitewide/controls/Interstitial_Spinner.gif'"+
    " class='floatLeft' alt='loader image'/><h2 class='loaderText'>" + b + "</h2></div>"
      , f = "auto";
      /////////////////// Executes only till this.. 
    "small" == c ? (e = "<div class='loadingContainer'><span class='aria-hidden' aria-live='assertive' id='LoadingId_small' "+
    "   aria-atomic='true'></span>"+
    "   <img src='" + imgPath + "/content/Interstitial_Spinner.gif' class='floatLeft' alt='loader image'/>"+
    "   <h2 class='loaderText'>" + b + "</h2></div>",
    f = "455") : 
    "medium" == c ? (e = "<div class='mediumLoaderContainer'>"+
    "   <span class='aria-hidden' aria-live='assertive' id='LoadingId_medium' aria-atomic='true'></span>"+
    "   <img src='" + imgPath + "/content/Extra.jpg' class='promotionalImage' alt='promotional image'/>"+
    "   <img src='" + imgPath + "/content/Interstitial_Spinner.gif' class='floatLeft loadingImage' alt='loader image'/>"+
    "   <h2 class='loaderText'>" + b + "</h2></div>",
    f = "500"),
    $(a).html(e),
    interstitialLoaderReader("#LoadingId_" + c, b);
    .
    .
    .
    ....// so on
    $(".ui-dialog-content").css("width", "100%").css("padding", "0"),
    $(".ui-widget-content").css("background", "#FFFFFF")
}
```